# Error en Java, "Cannot inherit from final class error"

Tags: java

Obtengo este error, estoy utilizando algunas librerías de zxing.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
```

El código que ejecuto es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream barCodeInputStream;
    try {
        String IMG_PATH = "Ruta:\\imagen.png";
        barCodeInputStream = new FileInputStream(IMG_PATH);
        BufferedImage barCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(barCodeInputStream);

       // LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(barCodeBufferedImage);
       BufferedImageLuminanceSource  source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(barCodeBufferedImage);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);


        System.out.println("Barcode text is " + result.getText());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Creo que se cae en la siguiente línea:

```
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
```

Esa clase contiene lo siguiente:

```
public final class BinaryBitmap {

   private final Binarizer binarizer;
   private BitMatrix matrix;

   public BinaryBitmap(Binarizer binarizer) {
       if (binarizer == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Binarizer must be non-null.");
       }
       this.binarizer = binarizer;
   }
```

Y métodos más.

Edit 2:

La clase Binarizer:

```
public abstract class Binarizer {

  private final LuminanceSource source;

  protected Binarizer(LuminanceSource source) {
     this.source = source;
  }

  public final LuminanceSource getLuminanceSource() {
     return source;
  }

  public final int getWidth() {
     return source.getWidth();
  }

  public final int getHeight() {
     return source.getHeight();
  }

}
```

Comment: Y tu código ? Estás heredando de una final class, eso no se puede.

Comment: Y la clase HybridBinarizer ?

Comment: 1. El error no lo da en la línea indicada sino directamente al cargar la clase del main; al cargar las clases relacionadas se da cuenta del problema. 2. La línea que pones es correcta; si hubiera unas llaves (`new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source)) { ... }`) sí que estarías creando una clase nueva que hereda de `BinaryBitmap` (lo cual es imposible por ser ésta `final), tal como está sólo creas una instancia lo cual es completamente legal. 3. Este error ya te lo debería mostrar en el momento de compilar, intenta compilar todo el proyecto de nuevo

Comment: Y 4. Usa `java -verbose:class` para seguir [como se van cargando las clases](https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-verbose-options-java)

Comment: Lo de la línea que mencioné fue porque probé comentando esa línea hasta el final del main, y no hubo problema; luego descomenté la línea que puse arriba, y recién saltó el error, por lo que pienso que el error está ahí, o en la clase BinaryBitmap. En donde se encuentra realmente el problema? Agradezco su respuesta @SJuan76

Comment: Las posibilidades que veo son: 1) En el código que no has mostrado usas una clase que extiende una clase *final*. 2) supongo que `HybridBinarizer` es parte de ZXing; en ese caso si cargas versiones diferentes de los distintos jars de la librería pueden pasar cosas inesperadas como éstas. Usa el verbose, y haz pruebas eliminando una de las librerías (por ejemplo `new BinaryBitmap(null)`; aunque falle la ejecución por el null, si el programa se empieza a ejecutar sabrás que no es culpa de esta clase).

Comment: Encontré el problema. Había añadido varias librerías, y en dos de ellas, tenía  clases con el mismo nombre y la misma ruta, esa clase era GlobalHistogramBinarizer, en una de las librerías esta clase estaba declarada como final class, y en otra librería no. Y la clase HybridBinarizer estaba extendiendo de ella, y apuntaba a la clase de la librería en la cual GlobalHistogramBinarizer era declarada como final class.

Comment: Gracias por los datos, me ayudaron a encontrar el problema. @SJuan76

Comment: Si puedes describir de forma razonablemente corta lo que hiciste para detectar que clases te daban el conflicto, estaría bien que lo pusieras como respuesta para que quien tenga el mismo problema pueda encontrar tu pregunta y ver la solución. No hay problema en hacer una pregunta y escribir tu mismo la solución, de hecho se aniima a la gente a hacerlo. Incluso puedes añadirle a tu respuesta la marca de "Solución aceptada".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el problema. Había añadido varias librerías de ZXing, y en dos de ellas, tenía clases con el mismo nombre y la misma ruta, esa clase era GlobalHistogramBinarizer, en una de las librerías esta clase estaba declarada como final class, y en otra librería no. Y la clase HybridBinarizer estaba extendiendo de ella, y apuntaba a la clase de la librería en la cual GlobalHistogramBinarizer era declarada como final class. Gracias a @SJuan76 por ayudarme. Saludos!